# call R function directly from R script in Qt

Tags: c++, r, qt, rcpp, rinside

I would like to know if I could call R function already created in R script inside Qt push button.

As Qt is based on C++ language. I know that I can use "RInside" and "Rcpp" libraries to run R inside C++ code. However, this require changing the R function to be compatible with C++ format. In my case, my R functions are already in R script and I do not want to change them or re-write them in R-C++ format.

Is there a way to call the function directly without rewrite it in C++ format?

Comment: That's exactly what RInside does. It puts the R interpreter _inside_ your C++ program allowing you to run your R code unmodified.  See the repo, and see the examples which include Qt examples: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside

Comment: I believe what he meant was to define a function in an `R script file` (i.e. `some_func <- function(arg) { ... }` and then call it from `C++` code.

Comment: yes exactly ! @MilanŠ

Answer (score 3):

Usually you already know the answer yourself, you just need to ask yourself the right question:

**"How would this work, without changing the C++ compiler?"**

`C++` is a *compiled language*, meaning that any application that you write in `C++` needs to be compiled into a binary file. The language itself is nothing but instructions for the compiler on what you expect to be the final result.

Looking at [rinside on github](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/) it is pretty straightforward how to implement  your function in C++ using it. And this is to an extent your only option. Here's why:

**Scripting languages** like `Python` and `R` work in a way that they have a main application called an `interpreter` which you instruct using the aforementioned **scripting language** on how to call existing functions from (usually) `C/C++` libraries. **That means** that if you write a function in `R` then you just define a "recipe" for the `R interpreter` on how it should (sequentially) call these library functions. But your function itself **IS NOT PART** of said library.

That being said I do not think it is possible to do what you ask, because most likely `rinside` just takes advantage of the already existing libraries used by the `R interpreter` and makes them accessible via an interface in `C++`.

Your best option is reconstructing the function you made in `C++` using `rinside` which looks very user friendly.

There is another option and that is that you would wrap the entire `R` application and make it part of the `C++ application` (i.e. you open it from your application and stream your commands into it) but that is much **more complicated** than just rewriting your function.

EDIT: Just a small note, the `rinside` library is co-authored by @Dirk Eddelbuettel with whom I had a chance to have a pleasant discussion on Stackoverflow. If you would've add `rcpp`, `rinside` or `cran` as a tag to your question. You would've most likely get an answer straight from an expert in this area.